# Pivot Field in Excel Userform

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, userform

I have written a VBA code that allow me to display pivot fields in a userform and it works well. By doublclicking on `ID_SAP` I can visualize all the information related `ID_SAP` on a userform.
But once the userform is closed the system show me this pop-up that I wouldn't visualize (screen attached).

[image]

Could anyone help me to hide this pop-up?

This is the code:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    UserForm1.Height = 500
    UserForm1.Width = 930
    'ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    'On Error Resume Next
    Dim WK1 As Workbook, DB As Worksheet, Supporto As Worksheet, Inserimento As Worksheet

    Set WK1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set DB = WK1.Worksheets("Foglio1")
    Set Supporto = WK1.Worksheets("Supporto")
    Set Inserimento = WK1.Worksheets("Sheet1 (2)")
   
    UltimaRiga1 = Supporto.Range("w1").Value
    ID = Supporto.Range("w2").Value

    TODAY = Inserimento.Range("a1").Value

    For i = 1 To UltimaRiga1
        If ActiveCell.Value = DB.Cells(i, 3) Then
            'descrizione = contratto-proroga...
            riferimento = DB.Cells(i, 2)
            id_contratto = DB.Cells(i, 3)
            descrizione = DB.Cells(i, 4)
            protocollo = DB.Cells(i, 5)
            motivo = DB.Cells(i, 6)
            affidamento = DB.Cells(i, 7)
            desc_gara = DB.Cells(i, 8)
            inizio = DB.Cells(i, 9)
            fine = DB.Cells(i, 10)
            fineff = DB.Cells(i, 11)
            lv1 = DB.Cells(i, 14)
            lv2 = DB.Cells(i, 15)
            lv3 = DB.Cells(i, 16)
            TextBox2.Text = DB.Cells(i, 17)
            TextBox1.Text = DB.Cells(i, 18)
            TextBox3.Text = DB.Cells(i, 19)
            cig = DB.Cells(i, 20)
            bs = DB.Cells(i, 21)
            importo = Format(DB.Cells(i, 22), "Standard")
            note = DB.Cells(i, 24)
            link = DB.Cells(i, 25)
            inizioeffettivo = DB.Cells(i, 29)
            frequenza = DB.Cells(i, 30)
            istat = DB.Cells(i, 31)
            lv1code = DB.Cells(i, 32)
            lv2code = DB.Cells(i, 33)
            lv3code = DB.Cells(i, 34)
  
            qty1 = DB.Cells(i, 35)
            qty2 = DB.Cells(i, 36)
            qty3 = DB.Cells(i, 37)
            qty4 = DB.Cells(i, 38)
            qty5 = DB.Cells(i, 39)
            qty6 = DB.Cells(i, 40)

            qty1desc = DB.Cells(i, 41)
            qty2desc = DB.Cells(i, 42)
            qty3desc = DB.Cells(i, 43)
            qty4desc = DB.Cells(i, 44)
            qty5desc = DB.Cells(i, 45)
            qty6desc = DB.Cells(i, 46)

            pmedio1 = Format(DB.Cells(i, 47), "Standard")
            pmedio2 = Format(DB.Cells(i, 48), "Standard")
            pmedio3 = Format(DB.Cells(i, 49), "Standard")
            pmedio4 = Format(DB.Cells(i, 50), "Standard")
            pmedio5 = Format(DB.Cells(i, 51), "Standard")
            pmedio6 = Format(DB.Cells(i, 52), "Standard")

            app1 = DB.Cells(i, 53)
            app2 = DB.Cells(i, 54)
            app3 = DB.Cells(i, 55)
            app4 = DB.Cells(i, 56)
            app5 = DB.Cells(i, 57)
            app6 = DB.Cells(i, 58)
      
            app1desc = DB.Cells(i, 59)
            app2desc = DB.Cells(i, 60)
            app3desc = DB.Cells(i, 61)
            app4desc = DB.Cells(i, 62)
            app5desc = DB.Cells(i, 63)
            app6desc = DB.Cells(i, 64)
     
            papp1 = Format(DB.Cells(i, 65), "Standard")
            papp2 = Format(DB.Cells(i, 66), "Standard")
            papp3 = Format(DB.Cells(i, 67), "Standard")
            papp4 = Format(DB.Cells(i, 68), "Standard")
            papp5 = Format(DB.Cells(i, 69), "Standard")
            papp6 = Format(DB.Cells(i, 70), "Standard")
 
            Me.bozza = DB.Cells(i, 72)
            Me.stimato = DB.Cells(i, 73)
            Me.accessori = DB.Cells(i, 74)
        Else
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```